# iPhone app crashes at the mid of running or during launch

Tags: iphone, memory, crash

I have an issue in my application. My iPhone application crashes at mid of running or during the application launch at times both in iPhone and simulator.

I know that memory management is not proper or is it because of some other reasons.

My application is using a web service that pulls the data and displays it in the view, the web service is working properly because i see the data coming from the web service into my app.

Can anybody suggest how to manage memory properly i.e. where i have to release the objects,what are the objects that has to be released and the objects that should not be released.

Comment: It's going to be next to impossible for anyone to debug an application crash *without any source code*. Or is the last paragraph your actual question, and you're just hoping someone will explain everything there possibly is to know about memory management?

Comment: Hello i didnt ask anyone to debug by application and i also never expect anybody to explain everything about memory management.I just asked the possibilities where the app may crash.I followed the solution given by David Schiefer and it worked fine.

Comment: If you don't have a solution please don't imitate others question and thanks a lot for posting this reply

Answer (score 1):

You can start by reading Apple's [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1) and [this article](http://akosma.com/2009/01/28/10-iphone-memory-management-tips/) might also be helpful.

If you can provide some code that might be causing you problems, you should share it here for further assistance.

Comment: Irene thanks for the article which gives the memory management tips,it was really useful.I followed David's solutioj and i got the solution

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes an iPhone app crashes if you put too much code into `init` or `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. This has happened to me when I put too many download queries into `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and the app simply quit after a  while while never showing my interface because it was simply **overloaded with tasks**. Try moving all the webcode into a separate selector and then calling `performSelector:@selector(loadMyWebCode) withObject:nil afterDelay:1]` into `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, then it should work.

Comment: Thanks David,my application works fine without any crashes now.Thanks for the interest you took in answering my question